# Java swing duplica los JTextField al redimensionar

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

Buenas, e estado estudiando un poco de diseño de interfaces de usuario en Java y me a surgido un problema, el caso esta en que al añadir a un JPanel una entrada de texto (Con JTextField) y cambiar el tamaño de la ventana, se crean varias celdas mas, cuando tengo entendido que esto no debería ser asi, ¿se os ocurre donde esta el error?

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*; 
public class AWTUserWriting {

public static void main(String args[]){

    Frame frame = new Frame();

}

}

class Frame extends JFrame{
public Frame(){
    setTitle("Hola Usuario");
    setSize(300, 400);
    setResizable(true);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    VentanaTexto text = new VentanaTexto();
    add(text);

}
}

class VentanaTexto extends JPanel{

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setLocation(0,300);
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
    add(textField);
    JButton boton = new JButton("send");
    add(boton);
}
}
```

Comment: Hola AngryMasther. No podemos depurar por ti. Puedes mostrar logs o más informacion para aclarar la pregunta? Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Saludos angrymasther.

Tu problema radica en el método `paintComponent(Graphics g)` de la clase `VentanaTexto`.

La razón por la cuál aparecen más componentes es porque estás **creando** esos nuevos componentes en ese método y luego los estás agregando al panel. El método `paintComponent` se ejecuta varias veces cuando ocurren cambios en la ventana principal (lo que llama al método `repaint()`) en esta clase, en este caso, ocurrirá cuando cambias el tamaño de la ventana.

Además, no utilices el método `paintComponent` para instanciar nuevos componentes o ajustar configuraciones iniciales. Para eso está el constructor de clase.

Para evitar este comportamiento, tu clase `VentanaTexto` debería verse así:

```
class VentanaTexto extends JPanel{
    JTextField textField; // Los declaro aquí porque es posible que necesites usarlos más adelante en otro lugar de tu clase, o incluso fuera de este
    JButton boton;    

    public VentanaTexto() {
        setLocation(0,300);
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        add(textField);
        boton = new JButton("send");
        add(boton);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```